# Calculate the amount of overlap minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Start,                  Stop,                   Machine,   Prodid
2017-09-11 06:36:37.000 2017-09-11 07:41:35.000 CNC M 6 17-012811
2017-09-11 07:49:27.000 2017-09-11 10:10:01.000 CNC M 6 17-012811
2017-09-11 09:34:46.000 2017-09-11 10:10:01.000 CNC M 7 17-012738
2017-09-11 10:14:50.000 2017-09-11 11:50:15.000 CNC M 6 17-012811
2017-09-11 10:15:50.000 2017-09-11 11:50:15.000 CNC M 7 17-012738
2017-09-11 11:55:52.000 2017-09-11 12:17:03.000 CNC M 6 17-012811
2017-09-11 11:56:15.000 2017-09-11 12:17:14.000 CNC M 7 17-012738
```

I need to calculate the amount of overlapping machine running time in minutes. Is there a need way to do so? With Lag or Lead?
Or do I do it with a subquery? I work on SQL Server 2016.

Comment: What is the overlapping condition? please add the expected result.

Comment: The Overlapping Condition Stopvalue Entry > Start Value Next Entry

Comment: Look at entries 2 and three. They run parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this query. I subtract overlapped start time from stop time.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(Start DATETIME, [Stop] DATETIME,Machine VARCHAR(20),Prodid VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES

('2017-09-11 06:36:37.000','2017-09-11 07:41:35.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 07:49:27.000','2017-09-11 10:10:01.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 09:34:46.000','2017-09-11 10:10:01.000','CNC M 7','17-012738'),
('2017-09-11 10:14:50.000','2017-09-11 11:50:15.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 10:15:50.000','2017-09-11 11:50:15.000','CNC M 7','17-012738'),
('2017-09-11 11:55:52.000','2017-09-11 12:17:03.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 11:56:15.000','2017-09-11 12:17:14.000','CNC M 7','17-012738')

SELECT T1.*, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Ovr.Start , T1.[Stop])  Overlapping FROM @Tbl T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Tbl T2 WHERE T2.Start > T1.Start AND T2.Start < T1.Stop ORDER BY T2.Start) ) AS Ovr
```

Result

```
Start                   Stop                    Machine              Prodid               Overlapping
----------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
2017-09-11 06:36:37.000 2017-09-11 07:41:35.000 CNC M 6              17-012811            NULL
2017-09-11 07:49:27.000 2017-09-11 10:10:01.000 CNC M 6              17-012811            36
2017-09-11 09:34:46.000 2017-09-11 10:10:01.000 CNC M 7              17-012738            NULL
2017-09-11 10:14:50.000 2017-09-11 11:50:15.000 CNC M 6              17-012811            95
2017-09-11 10:15:50.000 2017-09-11 11:50:15.000 CNC M 7              17-012738            NULL
2017-09-11 11:55:52.000 2017-09-11 12:17:03.000 CNC M 6              17-012811            21
2017-09-11 11:56:15.000 2017-09-11 12:17:14.000 CNC M 7              17-012738            NULL
```

Comment: Thanks this will help

Comment: You're welcome! For close the question, could you mark as correct?

Comment: Sarslan what does Ovr.Start mean?

Comment: Ovr.Start next machine start time. I think that previous machine should stop before that time.  If it continues it make overlap.

Comment: it comes from outer apply join.