# Overlaps from multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Overlaps II

```
Start                     Stop                      Machine     Prodid      Overlap
2017-09-11 05:30:16.000   2017-09-11 10:41:40.000   CNC M 10    17-012424   281 
2017-09-11 06:00:42.000   2017-09-11 06:38:56.000   CNC M 9     17-012793   36 
2017-09-11 06:02:52.000   2017-09-11 13:03:39.000   CNC M 1     17-012808   415 
2017-09-11 06:08:39.000   2017-09-11 13:55:19.000   CNC M 11    17-012512   439 
2017-09-11 06:36:37.000   2017-09-11 07:41:35.000   CNC M 6     17-012811   57
```

Hi based on [Sarslan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46647462/6611487), I worked on my problem. In my previous example, we only focused on the next entry to estimate the overlap.

Is there a chance to expand the SQL code so that we look at all entries if they run parallel?

For example: The first entry goes until `10:41`. It runs parallel with the next 5 more entries. So the overlap should be more.

Here is the code from a previous example.

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE(Start DATETIME, [Stop] DATETIME,Machine VARCHAR(20),Prodid VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Tbl VALUES

('2017-09-11 06:36:37.000','2017-09-11 07:41:35.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 07:49:27.000','2017-09-11 10:10:01.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 09:34:46.000','2017-09-11 10:10:01.000','CNC M 7','17-012738'),
('2017-09-11 10:14:50.000','2017-09-11 11:50:15.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 10:15:50.000','2017-09-11 11:50:15.000','CNC M 7','17-012738'),
('2017-09-11 11:55:52.000','2017-09-11 12:17:03.000','CNC M 6','17-012811'),
('2017-09-11 11:56:15.000','2017-09-11 12:17:14.000','CNC M 7','17-012738')

SELECT T1.*, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, Ovr.Start , T1.[Stop])  Overlapping FROM @Tbl T1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @Tbl T2 WHERE T2.Start > T1.Start AND T2.Start < T1.Stop ORDER BY T2.Start) ) AS Ovr
```

Comment: "Is there a chance to expand the sql code ". What code? Also please format the data so it's readable. And also "the overlap should be more". More than what? How much more? A specific, precise example of what you mean with both input and output values would be useful, as would a statement of the general requirement. As it stands, the question is vague and unclear, does not describe an actual problem, and mentions code which we can't see, and therefore cannot help you to fix.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, provide desired results.

Comment: Sql Server 2016

Comment: What is the expected output based on that sample data?

Comment: To generate the overal amount of overlapping times of all entries.

Comment: This is a KPI for us. You can steer the production. You have to increase the amount of overlaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael,

I'm not making any efficiency claims for this, but roughly speaking, this might do what you want.

I don't have 2016, so you may get some new wizardry there that I haven't contemplated.

See how it goes ....

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT 
    A.Start, A.Stop, A.Machine, A.Prodid
    , SUM(DATEDIFF(n, 
         CASE WHEN B.Start > A.Start THEN B.Start ELSE A.Start END, 
         CASE WHEN A.Stop < B.Stop THEN A.Stop ELSE B.Stop END)
      ) AS overlap
    , COUNT(B.Start) AS [#Overlaps]
FROM            
    test.tbl AS A     LEFT OUTER JOIN
    test.tbl AS B     ON B.Start < A.Stop AND B.Stop > A.Start AND (A.Start < B.Start OR B.Start IS NULL)
GROUP BY A.Start, A.Stop, A.Machine, A.Prodid
ORDER BY A.Start
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael,

If row 1 overlaps row 2 by 1 hour, 
and also overlaps row 3 by 2 hours.

What value do you want to see as 'overlap' on row 1?

Do you need any indication of how may other rows have been overlapped?

Thanks

Comment: Simon, I like to see the overal amount of overlapping. In your post it would be 5 hours. It would be nice to also an indication about how many other rows are overlapping.

Comment: This kpi would really help us.